# Need to improve sql performance

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
Table temporary_search_table
post_id,property_status, property_address,....more 30 field

Table search_meta
meta_id,search_id,status,created_date
```

Ok I need  Total data which created_date is yesterday. For each temporary_search_table data there may multiple entry within search_meta. So we need to pick last one field from search_meta and check created date is yesterday and property_status is pending. if yes then we can count the number. If there is no data available in search_meta for entry in temporary_search_table then we dont need to count that row within our results.

Here i am attaching my sql data. its work but for 30000 row it take lots of time.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM temporary_search_table 
    WHERE property_status = 'pending' AND (1 = (SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_date) 
    FROM search_meta WHERE post_id = search_id ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0,1 ))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the two tables?

Comment: sorry may be i didn't understand your question. did you mean relation between table temporary_search_table and search_meta ?? if "yes" then yes. post_id in temporary_search_table is foreign key(search_id) in serach_meta table.

Comment: Well, there's a correlated sub query in there.

Comment: @MonirulIslam No, I mean is there an index on the `property_status` column in `temporary_search_table` and an index on the `post_id` column in `search_meta`?

Comment: No indexing available.

Comment: @MonirulIslam No indexing - slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking the indexes on your table, it would probably be better to not use a correlated sub query and use a straight join instead.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM temporary_search_table 
INNER JOIN search_meta ON post_id = search_id
WHERE property_status = 'pending' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_date) = 1
ORDER BY created_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you post me tutorial for DB indexing?

Comment: @MonirulIslam Did you test this SQL first?

Comment: Yes, i have tested. but seems slow :(

Comment: @MonirulIslam Then I would suggest `EXPLAIN <query>` to see what's wrong; also `SHOW CREATE TABLE temporary_search_table`.